# Shell select data with SPARQL and upload to virtuoso

Tags: bash, shell, sparql, virtuoso

I am trying to run the following script to load RDF data into a Virtuoso store. The script runs fine, but it appears that nothing is uploaded to Virtuoso, as the SPARQL query does not display any results. Any ideas why?

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba <<EOF
 SPARQL CREATE GRAPH <free>;
 ld_dir('/home/najib', 'term.rdf', 'free');
 rdf_loader_run();
 SPARQL SELECT * FROM <free> WHERE {?s ?o ?p};
 EOF
```

Comment: Is that space in your `EOF` line intentional?

Comment: I think your call to [ld_dir()](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ld_dir.html) likely has incorrect arguments for your desired data load.  Other questions specifically regarding [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com)  (from my employer) are generally best raised on the [public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 1):

Quote your heredoc `EOF`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/isql 1111 dba dba <<'EOF'
SPARQL CREATE GRAPH <free>;
ld_dir('/home/najib', 'term.rdf', 'free');
rdf_loader_run();
SPARQL SELECT * FROM <free> WHERE {?s ?o ?p};
EOF
```

As per `man bash`:

> No  parameter  expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, or pathname expansion is performed
>          on word.  If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote  removal  on  word,
>          and  the  lines in the here-document are not expanded.  **If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-docu‐
>          ment are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.**  In the  lat‐
>          ter case, the character sequence \ is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $,
>          and `.

**PS:** Also make sure there is no space before closing `EOF`

Comment: Thanks for answering! The queries are actually executed fine! Every function runs properly.. I tried your code, but I still get the same..

Comment: Are you sure query is executing fine?

Comment: Yes it is. The problem is that even when I  try the commands from the shell directly (without using a script) it gives  the same results.. I think only someone familiar with Virtuoso can help in this, as i believe it is not the problem of the script itself..